# New WebKit with old Qt. Is it worth trying?

Tags: c++, qt, webkit

I have a project built with Qt 3.2.3. It's a little outdated piece of code, but it works fine except for its' embedded browser. This thing is plain old. So I want to take fresh nightly built WebKit and try to adopt it somehow. The question is - is it even possible? I am new with Qt, but had a little experience with WebKit in the recent past. It was very easy linking it to C# project, but I really don't know about Qt and C++.

Maybe there is some better solution for updating a Qt browser without touching the whole Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly saying I think it's easier to port an application from 3.* to latest 4/5 then compiling latest WebKit into 3.*.. there are some core differences which will be really hard to solve. Although such experiment can be possible but I just not sure it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

WebKit from SVN won't even build against Qt from a couple months ago, so I can't imagine it would be easy to get it to build against Qt 3. I would highly recommend just porting to the current version of Qt and QtWebKit.